# parsing ini file failed during AJAX request

Tags: php, json, ajax, parsing

I'm trying to write an AJAX request but the response from the server is not valid because it is an error.

The response: `<br /> <b>Warning</b>:  parse_ini_file(config/config.ini): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\php\eindwerk\src\Promptopolis\Framework\Db.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />`

So it cannot parse the config.ini file so it can also not make a db connection.

However, on the page itself before I try the AJAX request, I already get data from the db, this is all correct and gets displayed without problems. So the config file does get parsed before sending an AJAX request.

I don't know why it fails to parse the config.ini file when sending an AJAX request specifically.

**my DB.php:**

```
<?php
    namespace Promptopolis\Framework;

    abstract class Db {
        private static $conn;

        private static function getConfig(){
            // get the config file
            return parse_ini_file("config/config.ini");
        }
        

        public static function getInstance() {
            if(self::$conn != null) {
                // REUSE our connection
                return self::$conn;
            }
            else {
                // CREATE a new connection
                
                // get the configuration for our connection from one central settings file
                $config = self::getConfig();
                $database = $config['database'];
                $user = $config['user'];
                $password = $config['password'];
                $host = $config['host'];

                self::$conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=".$database, $user, $password);
                return self::$conn;
            }
        }
    }
```

**My script:**

```
   <script>
        //add click event to voted button
        const voted = document.querySelector('[name="voted"]');
        //add eventlistener
        voted.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            //get user id
            let user_id = <?php echo $id ?>;

            //create formdata object
            let formData = new FormData();
            //append user id to formdata
            formData.append('user_id', user_id);
            fetch("ajax/votes.php", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formData
                })
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(json){
                    //update counter
                    voting.innerHTML = json.votes;
                });
            
        });
    </script>
```

**My votes.php:**

```
<?php
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

    $user = new \Promptopolis\Framework\User();
    $moderator = new \Promptopolis\Framework\Moderator();
    $moderator->updateVotes($user_id);
    $user->checkAdmin($user_id);
    $votes = $user->getVotes($user_id);

    $result = [
        "status" => "success",
        "message" => "Vote was saved",
        "votes" => $votes
    ];

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: The script cannot find the file config/config.ini. Has to do with relative path. Where is votes.php in relation to the script that includes the java script?

Comment: @JasonK The votes.php path is ajax/votes.php, in the root I have a profile.php file with the script in that file. I haven't moved it to a .js file yet.

Comment: Are you using a framework or rolling your own? When you called the votes.php it's starting spot is now ajax/ So now when you open any files it's now looking or ajax/that.file. In the case of your config ajax/config/config.ini

Comment: Have you checked the web server error log? That might have some more info in it.

Comment: @JasonK I copied my config/config.ini into the ajax folder. Now it works. But is there a way that I can have just one config.ini file that works for both instead of one seperatly for the AJAX requests?

Comment: Change `parse_ini_file("config/config.ini")` to `parse_ini_file("/full/path/to/config/config.ini")` or `parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/config.ini")`

Comment: You need to look at the [$_SERVER Server and execution environment information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) global. This has path information to help you find where you are at. Also look at [Superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) for some more details. Short answer put the full path in the db.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

I had to change `parse_ini_file("config/config.ini")` to `parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/config.ini")`

This way the ini file is able to be parsed from within the ajax folder.